# Spring Boot Repository Test with @DataJpaTest fails after update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I recently updated Spring Boot from 2.3 to 2.4. Since that all Repository tests failing with the error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '...RepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repositoryUnderTest'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '...Repository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

My test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Profile("test")
public class RepositoryTest {

   @Autowired
   Repository repositoryUnderTest;
}
```

This is the repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {
   ...
}
```

As I said that just happened after the update. Before updating Spring Boot at version 2.3.12 everything was working fine. I already searched through the release notes but could not find anything which could cause this issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: replace `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` with `@SpringBootTest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get all the tests running again, was replacing `@DataJpaTest` with

```
@SpringBootTest 
@Transactional
```

Comment: See answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640506/repository-in-datajpatest-initialized-to-null